# In Django, I know how to build a template. render_to_response('something.html'). But, how do I include a JSON object in there?

Tags: javascript, django, json, object, templates

When the page loads, I have a JavaScript function that needs to analyze the JSON. But, this JSON must be present when I load "something.html"

I know how to do this, but  I don't know how to combine them together.

```
return HttpResponse(thejson, mimetype="application/javascript")
```

Comment: It would help to show what you think you want sent.  Is this being sent to a browser?  How will the JavaScript start? Are you saying it won't be embedded in an HTML page?  How will the JavaScript find/read the JSON document?

Answer (score 3):

If you want the json to be in your template from the start, just pass it in like any other variable:

```
return render_to_response('something.html', {'json':thejson, 'othervariable':foo})
```

Comment: Then, how would I include it? LIke this? {{thejson}}

Comment: In my example, `{{ json }}`, because I called the dictionary key (the bit in quotes) `'json'`.

Comment: Why do we use a template to return a simple json ?

Comment: @Glide you wouldn't necessarily, but the OP specifically wanted to include the JSON in the template.

Comment: Ok. So how can we just send a json response without any template ?